# Modulus system of equations and modular arithmetic.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

Let $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $-82 < r < 82$.

Let:
$p_1 = r/44$
$p_2 = r/42.8$
$m_1 = 21p_1$
$m_2 = 21p_2$

Given $ p_1 \pmod 1 $, $ m_1 \pmod 1$, $ m_2 \pmod 1 $ solve for $r$. As pointed out below, $ x \pmod 1 $ in this context is the same as $ x - \lfloor x \rfloor$. For clarity, I'm looking for a solution in the form below:

$r = f(p_1 \pmod 1,m_1 \pmod 1,m_2 \pmod 1) = $

I've written a MATLAB script which shows that there is one solution for $r$ when $r$ is bounded by $-82 < r < 82$, but I can't determine $r$ given only these results.

[image]

Comment: [MathJaX tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) Also $x \bmod 1$ is the same as $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ in this context.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, thanks for the tutorial. Hope that's better. I never touched modulo math in university but need it now for a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$. Also, let $a=\{p_1\}, b=\{m_1\},c=\{m_2\}$.

Then, we want to solve the following system for $r$ when we are given $a,b,c$ :

$$\begin{cases}a=\{\frac{r}{44}\}\\\\
b=\{\frac{21r}{44}\}
\\\\c=\{\frac{105r}{214}\}\end{cases}$$

Now, since $-82\lt r\lt 82$, we have $\lfloor\frac{r}{44}\rfloor=-2,-1,0,1$.

So, we have
$$\frac{r}{44}=a-2,a-1,a,a+1,$$
i.e.
$$r=44(a-2),44(a-1),44a,44(a+1)$$

Therefore, the answer is
$$r=\begin{cases}44(a-2)&\text{if $\quad b=\{21(a-2)\}\quad $ and $\quad c=\{\frac{2310(a-2)}{107}\}$}
\\\\44(a-1)&\text{if $\quad b=\{21(a-1)\}\quad $ and $\quad c=\{\frac{2310(a-1)}{107}\}$}
\\\\44a&\text{if $\quad b=\{21a\}\quad $ and $\quad c=\{\frac{2310a}{107}\}$}
\\\\44(a+1)&\text{if $\quad b=\{21(a+1)\}\quad $ and $\quad c=\{\frac{2310(a+1)}{107}\}$}\end{cases}$$

where $a=\{p_1\},b=\{p_2\},c=\{m_2\}$ with $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. This answer is technically correct and works well for the numbers, and will work for the project I'm working on. I'm a little sad that there's no solution that isn't piece-wise, but that's okay. Thanks again!